# avoiding code duplication in different classes where the function does the same in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm kinda new to OOP so this question feels a bit weird but I want to know what I should do in this case

Say I have a Tup4 class which just holds 4 doubles, and two classes Point4 and Vec4 that extend Tup4. Now, checking for equality in Tup4 is just comparing whether all 4 doubles in each tuple are (approximately) equal. This holds in both classes extending it. However, it makes no sense to define an equality function in Tup4, because then I would be able to check for equality between a Point and a Vector, which doesn't make much sense. So I can't define a virtual equals method in Tup4, so what can I do? The code is exactly the same in both cases, the only difference is the type of the function. So I want to know if I can avoid having two methods

```
bool equals(Point4 p);
bool equals(Vec4 v);
```

Where they both do the same but are defined in different classes

Comment: Maybe you want to write a function template: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

Comment: Using `virtual` here looks like a bad idea.  Vectors and points are the kind of thing you'll want to have millions of in packed buffers, for whom virtual/reference overhead is serious.  And runtime polymophic usage of the two types is going to rare (exctremely so) corner cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tup4 is a concept not a class.  Vec4 snd Point4 satisfy that concept.

Most of Vec4 and Point4 are implemented as templates.

In the rare case you need to handle Tup4s in runtime polymophic way, don't use inheritance, use type erasure like std function.  But you probably won't.

```
struct Tup4Data{
  double v[4];
};
template<class D>
struct Tup4Impl:Tup4Data{
  // common implementation details of Tup4
  // D is derived class (Vec4 or Point4)
};

struct Vec4:Tup4Impl<Vec4>{
  // extra stuff for Vec4
};
struct Point4:Tup4Impl<Point4>{
  // extra stuff for Poimt4
};
```

Now, code that just wants to work on raw doubles and doesn't care can take `Tup4Data`.  `Tup4Impl` uses the CRTP if you want to look it up; this provides *static* polymorphism.

Those that care if it is a vector or a point can take either one.

Those that wants to take both and behave differently can be template code, or type erase.

This last case -- type erase -- is harder, but in exchange you get massive improvements in every other case.  And 99% of code bases don't even need to type erase.

I'm not even certain what kind of situation has code that wants to type erase here.

So just don't worry about it.  (If you want to learn, look up example std function implementations).

Comment: `Tup4Data` should probably be a `std::array`.

Comment: @ulrich possibly.  Or inherit from it, to allow data level methods to be added.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you already accepted an answer, but here's what I was going to
I propose without going down the template route:

Define an equality method in your Tup4 class, but leave it protected:

```
class Tup4
{
public:
    double a, b, c, d;

    
protected:
    bool EqualityCheck(const Tup4& other) const
    {
        return (a == other.a && b == other.b && c == other.c && d == other.d);
    }

};
```

Then your `Point4` and `Vec4` classes can have overloaded equality operators that call the parent's method:

```
class Point4 : public Tup4
{
public:
    bool operator==(const Point4& other) const
    {
        return EqualityCheck(other);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use templates for this.

It actually is not a good use OOP to shoehorn value-like types such as mathematical vectors and points into an object hierarchy. Object hierarchies mean using "reference semantics"; whereas, vectors, tuples, and points want to be values.

Look at, for example, [how the C++ standard library implements complex numbers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex). It implements them as a class template parametrized on the number type you'd like to use e.g. float, double, etc. and then overloads the arithmetic operators to handle `complex<T>`.

How you would really implement a vector etc. class is similar.

Answer (score 1):

You want the two types Point4 and Vector4 to be incompatible with each other, in the sense that they are different types. Now, as yourself what you need the Tuple4 for. Is it really important that Point4 is a Tuple4? In other words, is the Liskov Substitution Principle important there? My guess is that the answer is that Tuple4 is just a convenient baseclass for code reuse, not for OOP reasons.

If my assumption is correct, using a private baseclass would be a better choice. Since the base is private, it won't allow comparing Vector4 and Point4. For convenient code reuse, you can forward to the baseclass implementations:

```
class Point4: Tuple4 {
public:
    bool operator==(Point4 const& rhs) const {
        return static_cast<Tuple4 const&>(*this) == static_cast<Tuple4 const&>(rhs);
    }
};
```

That said, consider using `std::array` as baseclass instead of writing your own.

Comment: makes a lot of sense, thank you

Comment: I have to ask though, how do I make the parent class private in this case?

Comment: `class`: everything private by default. `struct`: everything public by default. That also applies to base classes, which is why you usually write `class derived: public base ...`.